# MongoDB model for cross vendor time series data

Tags: mongodb

I know my problem seems better be solved by RDBMS models. But I really want to deploy it using MongoDB because I have potential irregular fields to add on each record in the future and also want to practice my NoSQL database skills.

PE ratio and PB ratio data provided by one vendor:

```
| Vendor5_ID|   PE|    PB|date       |
|----------:|----:|-----:|:----------|
|        210| 3.90| 2.620|2017-08-22 |
|        210| 3.90| 2.875|2017-08-22 |
|        228| 3.85| 2.320|2017-08-22 |
|        214| 3.08| 3.215|2017-08-22 |
|        187| 3.15| 3.440|2017-08-22 |
|        181| 2.76| 3.460|2017-08-22 |
```

Price data and analyst covering provided by another vendor

```
|Symbol | Price| Analyst|date       |
|:------|-----:|-------:|:----------|
|AAPL   |   160|       6|2017-08-22 |
|MSFT   |   160|       6|2017-08-22 |
|GOOG   |   108|       4|2017-08-22 |
```

And I have key convert data:

```
| uniqueID|Symbol |from       |to         |
|--------:|:------|:----------|:----------|
|        1|AAPL   |2016-01-10 |2017-08-22 |
|        2|MSFT   |2016-01-10 |2017-08-22 |
|        3|GOOG   |2016-01-10 |2017-08-22 |

| uniqueID| Vendor5_ID|from       |to         |
|--------:|----------:|:----------|:----------|
|        1|        210|2016-01-10 |2017-08-22 |
|        2|        228|2016-01-10 |2017-08-22 |
|        3|        214|2016-01-10 |2017-08-22 |
```

I want to execute time range query fast. I come up with an idea that store each column as a collection,

```
db.PE:
{
 _id,
 uniqueID, 
 Vendor5_ID,
 value,
 date
}

db.PB:
{
 _id,
 uniqueID, 
 Vendor5_ID,
 value,
 date
}

db.Price:
{
 _id,
 uniqueID, 
 Symbol,
 value,
 date
}

db.Analyst:
{
 _id,
 uniqueID, 
 Symbol,
 value,
 date
}
```

Is this a good solution? What model do you think is the best if there are far more data to add by different vendor?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using nested table or child table approach. I am not sure the extent of support mongo has for this kind of support. I would consider using Oracle NoSQL Database for this usecase with nested tables support with TTL and higher throughput (because of BDB as storage engine). With nested tables you could store PE and PB with timestamps in the child/nested table while the parent table continues to hold symbol/vendor_id and any other details. This will ensure that your queries are on the same shard, putting them in a different collection will not guarentee same shard.

Comment: Then it seems hard to do cross stock query (e.g. PE for  list of stocks at Sep 2016)